# Why does my finished R histogram not have the amount of bins I specified?

Tags: r, histogram, bins

I'm trying to visualize some numerical data to get a sense of how it is distributed, and am trying to graph it as a histogram to do so. However, the resulting histogram only seems to have 2 bins on the graph even when I try to specify more bins. This is my code:

```r
bins=seq(-14, 1.3, by=0.1)
hist(pheno$slope4, breaks=bins,xlim = c(-.2,.2))
```

My data is only numeric values (decimals), maybe with some NA values. I've also tried specifying breaks in the following ways:

```r
bins=c(-14, -0.2, -0.175, -0.15, -0.125, -0.1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 1.3)
breaks=100
```

[image: see histogram using first two lines of code here]

Comment: Welcome to SO, wystery! Can you provide some unambiguous sample data, such as from `data.frame(...)` or the contents of `pheno$slope4`. (Questions that need the full frame often include the output from `dput(head(x,20))`, though that is not as strictly needed/useful here.)

Comment: Why do you restrict the x-axis to just a small range of sequence of bins you have defined? That, to me, seems to be self-contradictory. I assume the histogram does have the amount of bins you have specified but that amount cannot be shown because you've limited the range of the x-axis.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the welcome, very new to this! Here are the first few lines of pheno$slope4:  [1] -0.0068780 -0.0177200 -0.0232400 -0.0066180 -0.0079920 -0.0063170
   [7] -0.0076510 -0.0092670 -0.0062490 -0.0122900 -0.0121800 -0.0098130
  [13] -0.0088900 -0.0095560 -0.0094410 -0.0131000 -0.0128500 -0.0092320 The max is 1.228000 and the min is -13.58000 though those are definitely outliers and the data I want should be approximately between -.2 and 0 (I'm trying to narrow my range)

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann That could be it? I have the x-axis limited to between -.2 and .2 because that's where I estimate my significant data to be, anything outside of that is bad data